# Gmail smtp not able to send email javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException:

Tags: smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail, digital-ocean

I have set gmail for less secure app already
Also set IMAP forwarding

Locally sending emails works but the problem occurs in

**digital ocean droplet [without ssl or domain]** via ip address

Email Setting using java simple mail

```
private EmailMailer(){
        setMailer(new Mailer(new ServerConfig("smtp.gmail.com", 587,EmailConstants.EMAIL_ID, EmailConstants.EMAIL_PASSWORD),
                TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS));
    }
```

Checked Digital ocean was able to connect to port 587

Getting error while sending mail

```
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuD
ww-app_1    | 534-5.7.14 ywow3CZ7TbpX5mHNs0LChqgXAsXoucspMfedy2oAIDqjP0MH4RO8M_1bLvhh6f3Ha0Fj_a
ww-app_1    | 534-5.7.14 RhfPx0WlDHIfsXUR8rbVLiSrSAr-hfc0PsOweMs0xMqQhHb6LhXMusyjtsfGzF> Please
ww-app_1    | 534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
ww-app_1    | 534-5.7.14  Learn more at
ww-app_1    | 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a6sm8956026qth.74 - gsmtp
ww-app_1    | 
ww-app_1    |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:914)
ww-app_1    |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:825)
ww-app_1    |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:730)
ww-app_1    |   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
ww-app_1    |   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
ww-app_1    |   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
ww-app_1    |   at org.simplejavamail.mailer.internal.mailsender.MailSender.sendMailClosure(MailSender.java:252)
ww-app_1    |   ... 59 more
```

Comment: Is the two factor authentication of gmail is turned off for your account?

Comment: yes it is turned off

Comment: Then check wheather the `less secure apps` option is turned on or not in your google account.